# Why does Postgres discard timezone information with 'AT TIME ZONE'

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, converters

I have a postgres database with `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values. The values could have any arbitrary time zone. I now want to use the `date_trunc` function on those but in a specific timezone. I though I could use the `AT TIME ZONE` function to normalize all timestamps to one timezone, but as result I get a `TIMESTAMP` without time zone information.
e.g:

```
select now(), now() AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London';
              now              |          timezone          
-------------------------------+----------------------------
 2015-08-12 12:21:55.337973+02 | 2015-08-12 11:21:55.337973
```

What I want is to get the result with the time zone information attached to it like `2015-08-12 11:21:55.337973+01` but I can't seem to find a command for this.

My current solution is to use ``` AT TIME ZONE``, then using date_trunc on the ```TIMESTAMP`without timezone and`AT TIME ZONE``` again afterwards to re-attach the time zone information. However, it seems ugly to use it in that way:

```
SELECT
date_trunc('day', '2015-08-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz),
date_trunc('day', '2015-08-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London')
AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/London';

       date_trunc       |        timezone        
------------------------+------------------------
 2015-08-01 00:00:00+02 | 2015-07-31 01:00:00+02
```

My Questions would be:

1. Is there a postgresql command that converts a timestamp from one timezone to another without discarding the time zone information
2. Why does postgres behave in this way? Is there a reason fir discarding the time zone information?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: > ...TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE values. The values could have any
> arbitrary time zone

- I believe not. when you save the timestamptz to database it saves the UTC timstamp and info about time zone. so when you change daylight time, you come in the morning and all you timestamptz values are shown to you with an hour switch, comparing to yesterday... so then you probably saved those to text field? right?

Comment: @VaoTsun Actually `timestamp with time zone` stores no info about the TZ. It's stored in UTC and converted to/from the current db/client's `TimeZone` setting on the fly. There is no data type in PostgreSQL that stores time zone information, not even the confusingly named `timestamp with time zone`.

Comment: @CraigRinger That makes sense, so timestamptz are always in UTC, the db just converts them to the local time zone on the fly, which explains why I can't have a timestamptz with a different timezone. If I want that, the db has to create a different time object with the timestamp in the desired time zone.
I guess they decided  to store this timestamp without the time zone because they would otherwise have multiple timestamp types which are essentially the same but somehow still different.
Thanks. If you write an answer with this info, I will accept it.

Comment: @TimSchneider Well, we have that anyway :S . I think `timestamp with time zone` was done that way mostly because it's easier, and at the time it might not have been understood how limiting it is to force things to UTC. We should really have a true timestamp that carries the epoch time *and an associated time zone*, but it gets *really* complicated, fast. Which time zone? UTC offset? Regional time zone (subject to change, DST)? TZ abbreviation? It's a major, complicated job.

Comment: @CraigRinger - IIRC, doesn't `time with time zone` store the offset?  To store date+time+offset, One could store local values in two fields `date` and `time with time zone`, or one could store the UTC value in a `timestamp` (or `timestamptz`) and combine with a `smallint`  representing the offset (in minutes).  Still, would be nice if Postgres had a native `datetimeoffset` type like SQL Server. Perhaps a [user-defined type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xtypes.html) could be used?  I'd love to see an answer showing a UDT for a `datetimeoffset` type. :)